# How to analyze the force transferred by a rigid rod onto a point body in an overdamped situation?

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces, vectors

Let us assume that we are working in a low Reynolds number situation, so we have a first order relationship between force and displacement:

$$ F = \eta v$$

Rather than the usual $F = ma$.

Say that there is a rigid rod, with constant forces on its end as follows:[image]

Let the force on one end be $F_1$, and the force on the other end be $F_2$. At some point in time, the rigid rod makes contact with a point mass, at some point along its body:

[image]

Assume a coordinate system along the rod parametrized by $x$, starting from the end where $F_1$ is acting as $x = 0$, and going up to where $F_2$ is acting as $x = 1$. Thus we know three things: $F_1$, $F_2$, and $x$, the location where the point mass makes contact.

Let $F_p$ be the force transmitted to the point mass at the moment of contact. What is $F_p$ as a function of $F_1$, $F_2$ and $x$?

Comment: It is not clear to me what is the origin of the forces, and the relationship with your comment about low Reynolds numbers. It seems as though you are saying that the rod must be moving in a viscous liquid (in which case the direction and size of the forces tell us something about the motion of the rod, perhaps?) Also note that an impact does not result in a deterministic force - at best you get a known impulse (integral of force and time). And you would definitely need to know the length, and mass of the rod and the point mass.  Can you clarify?

Comment: @Floris Sure, let me try. Yes, the low Reynolds number assumption is similar to the "moving in a very viscous fluid" assumption, but is scale free (that is, very tiny objects inside a fairly non-viscous fluid like water, still have low Reynolds number and thus their motion is still first order: that is, inertia is negligible). Because inertia is negligible, the mass of the rod, or the point mass is not important. Instead, all that is important is the force exerted by the rod, on the point, at the moment of collision (we do not care what happens before or after collision).

Comment: @Floris You can assume the length of the rod is 1 unit length. Similarly, if you still feel that you need to know the mass of the rod, you can assume it is 1 unit mass.

Comment: Is inertia of your point mass important or does it follow the same laws as the rod? If the latter then can you interpolate the viscous forces between the ends? This still feels like a very contrived problem to me. What are you really trying to solve?